# Spark: Read by S3 aws-sdk or as RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have few (5-10), under 5KB config files in S3. Either these files can be read by using AWS S3 or by using RDD. So if there are 10 files, 10 RDD object is created, and used `collect()` to turn this into list.

Since RDD is distributed, is it advisable to read using aws-s3 Java SDK instead of RDD?

Answer (score 0):

You should always prefer passing the config files to the spark driver then reading them using python open command itself or java if you are using aws glue.

If you are using EMR or your native cluster then you can use boto3 to read the file and either pass it to the driver or process accordingly.

Comment: But why can't use RDD for such things?

Comment: RDD's are distributed and their default parallelism is 8 partitions. SO your data will get distributed to 8 partitions as soon you read it and everytime you collect it will be unnecessary movement of data across executors something which can be done easily by other methods. I mean you can use the RDD but that is something not recommended for such small task.